# Нахождение расстояния между двумя отрезками на плоскости

Tags: java, вычислительная-геометрия

Нужна помощь по теме "вычислительная геометрия". Нужно найти расстояние между двумя отрезками на плоскости. На вход дается 8-м чисел которые являются координатами концов этих отрезков, сначала первого, потом второго. Нужно найти расстояние между этими прямыми с точность 10^-6.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        Writer fr = new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"));

        pt a = new pt();
        a.getXY(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());

        pt b = new pt();
        b.getXY(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());

        pt c = new pt();
        c.getXY(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());

        pt d = new pt();
        d.getXY(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());


        double[] mas = new double[4];
        mas[0] = distPointToPoint(a, c);
        mas[1] = distPointToPoint(a, d);
        mas[2] = distPointToPoint(b, d);
        mas[3] = distPointToPoint(b, c);

        double minPointToPoint = mas[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < mas.length; i++) {
            minPointToPoint = Math.min(minPointToPoint, mas[i]);
        }


        double[] AllSkal = new double[4];
        AllSkal[0] = Skal(a, c, d);
        AllSkal[1] = Skal(b, c, d);
        AllSkal[2] = Skal(c, a, b);
        AllSkal[3] = Skal(d, a, b);


        double minPointToLine1;
        if (AllSkal[0] < 0)
            minPointToLine1  = Math.min(distPointToLine(a, c, d), minPointToPoint);
        else
            minPointToLine1 = minPointToPoint;

        // Первая чвсть
        double minPointToLine2;
        if (AllSkal[1] < 0)
            minPointToLine2 = Math.min(distPointToLine(b, c, d),minPointToPoint);
        else
            minPointToLine2 = minPointToPoint;

        // Вторая часть 
        double minPointToLine3;
        if (AllSkal[2] < 0)
            minPointToLine3 = Math.min(distPointToLine(c, a, b), minPointToPoint);
        else
            minPointToLine3 = minPointToPoint;

        // Третья часть 
        double minPointToLine4;
        if (AllSkal[3] < 0)
            minPointToLine4 = Math.min(distPointToLine(d, a, b), minPointToPoint);
        else
            minPointToLine4 = minPointToPoint;



        double minPointToLine = Math.min(Math.min(minPointToLine1,minPointToLine2),Math.min(minPointToLine3,minPointToLine4));
        String s = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000000").format(minPointToLine);
        fr.write(s + "");

        fr.close();
    }
    static class pt{
        int x;
        int y;

        void getXY (int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    static public double distPointToPoint (pt a, pt b)
    {
        return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
    }

    static public double distPointToLine (pt a, pt b, pt c)
    {
        double rez = Math.abs((c.y - b.y) * a.x - (c.x - b.x) * a.y + c.x * b.y - c.y * b.x);
        rez /= Math.sqrt((c.y - b.y) * (c.y - b.y) + (c.x - b.x) * (c.x - b.x));
        return rez;
    }

    static public double Skal (pt a, pt c, pt d)
    {
        pt vect_1 = new pt();
        vect_1.getXY(c.x - a.x, c.y - a.y);

        pt vect_2 = new pt();
        vect_2.getXY(d.x - c.x, d.y - c.x);

        return (vect_1.x * vect_2.x + vect_1.y * vect_2.y);
    }
}
```

Здесь я мыслил следующим образом, я нахожу минимальное расстояние от между всеми комбинациями точек (между a-d, a-c, b-d, b-c). Затем я считаю скалярное произведение чтобы между прямыми (a-c)(c-d), (b-c)(c-d), (c-a)(a-b), (d-a)(a-b) для того чтобы узнать могу ли я опустить перпендикуляр из точки на прямую. Если скалярное произведения строго меньше нуля значит угол между этими отрезками "тупой" (> 90 градусов), а значит если опустить перпендикуляр то он не попадет на этот отрезок (вроде бы -_-). Далее я нахожу те комбинации прямых и точек из которых можно опустить перпендикуляр на отрезок. Потом я ищу минимальное из длинны перпендикуляра и минимального расстояния между точками. Но что-то в этой "гениальной" схеме работает не так как не все тесты проходят. Да я знаю что нужно еще проверять не пересекаются ли они ну пока что я хочу разобраться с этим, но я все равно буду рад если вы подскажите способ это проверять)).

Доказательство того что программа работает не правильно (там не все тесты жалуются на случай где отрезки пересекаются)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900577/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

Как проверить пересекаются ли отрезки?
Находите коэффициенты а и b для уравнений прямых, частями которых являются отрезки.

`y1 = a1*x + b1` ; `y2 = a2*x + b2` - уравнения 

`x = (b2-b1)/(a1-a2)` - точка пересечения прямых

Проверяете что `x` принадлежит каждому из отрезков. Тогда они пересекаются.